# How to hide the Week numbers in the CalendarView (DatePicker)

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I am new to Android (and Java), please help me with this problem.

I am trying to hide the week numbers in the CalendarView in the DatePicker, found a Boolean set to true called:

```
mShowWeekNumber
```

inside

```
mCalendarView
```

in the DatePicker, but how can I set this value to false....??

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Set `mCalendarView.setShowWeekNumber(false)`.

Comment: Just found that it can be set directly in the XML with        android:showWeekNumber="false"

Answer (score 3):

*[This text of this answer was originally written by [Vikram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2558882/vikram)]*

Set `mCalendarView.setShowWeekNumber(false)`

Answer (score 3):

You can set it in the layout file.

By configuring the CalendarView to **android:showWeekNumber="false"**:

```
<CalendarView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="301dp"
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:showWeekNumber="false"/>
```